# Dúvidas sobre Django MTV

Tags: python, django

Estou com uma dificuldade de entender o conceito do Django.

Por favor, verifiquem se minha concepção está correta:

MTV se refere à Model Template View.
**Model** seria meu banco de dados.
**Template** seria a interface exibida pro usuário (HTML, por exemplo).
**View** seria minhas funções que tratam as informações do Model e apresentam no Template.

Portanto, desenvolvendo uma página de login seria:
**Model** - Meu banco de dados com as informações do usuário.
**Template** - A tela apresentada pro usuário inserir o login e senha.
**View** - É onde está minha função que valida as informações inseridas pelo usuário no Template junto do Model e retorna se a requisição está correta e pode prosseguir pra próxima página.

Correto?

Comment: Sim, parece estar correta.

Comment: E cada app seria uma página? No exemplo citado, a página de login é uma app, já a página que é apresentada após o login é outra app?